# Putting a Name from a <Param> into a Variable

Tags: php, mysql, html, variables

How would I put the following Param named "Movie" value into a variable?

I want a variable called 'Favorites' to equal the value of 'movie'? (the param name)

I have tried to word this before and just got my reputation subtracted, I don't exactly know how to word it.

Any advice on how I can accomplish this?

(Took out the video url and other stuff since the value won't be the same each time)

```
<param name="movie"      

    value="http://www.youtube.com/v/.........">

</param>
```

#### ***UPDATE***

I want to extract the Value from the Parameter not the 'Movie"

I want to extract the value of it not the whole code itself

Example:

$Favorites=movie.value

accursed this wouldn't work but it just a simple example I would like to figure out how to accomplish

Comment: This ultimately depends on where your handling this from. If your evaluating it while php is rendering the page its on. or your cURL/SOAP to get a page content and scraping it. They you might be able to use something like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to evaluate the objects in the DOM (kinda like how JavaScript would). Or if your evaluating it just as a string, you might be able to Regex it to break the string down. You might also be able to treat it like an XML object. Again in all depends on what your doing, how your doing it, and all else pertaining to getting that string.

Comment: its generationed upon video search results, then assigned the value according to the url of the embeded video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic form would be:

`$favorites = 'Movie'`

So:

```
<param name="<?php echo $favorites ?>"      

value="http://www.youtube.com/v/.........">

</param>
```

Comment: so would I need to use the "Include" statement within the php?

Comment: well I have Ajax that listen to a button click, once the button is clicked it calls the php code which which adds to the database (mysql) and now I need to add the html (or value of the above) into the database

Comment: It helps to include ALL relevant information in your original question.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. That information I truly didn't know I needed to state

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I follow what you're asking but here are a couple of possible solutions:

If you want the entire param element including all its contents as a PHP variable:

```
<?php $myvar = "<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/.........\"></param>";?>
```

If you just want the name of the param to be a variable:

```
<?php $param_name = "movie"; ?>

<param name="<?php echo $param_name; ?>"      

    value="http://www.youtube.com/v/.........">

</param>
```

If that's not what you're going for please update your post to explain a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

I would use simpledom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net rather than regex.

Then the code would be:

```
$html = str_get_html('<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/..."></param>');
$e = $html->find("param", 0);
$the_var = new stdClass;
$the_var->{$e->name} = $e->value; //$the_var->movie == "http://www.youtube.com/v/..."
```

Or looping through multiple param tags:

```
$html = str_get_html('<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/..."></param><param name="game" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/..."></param>');
foreach($html->find("param") as $param) {
    echo $param->name; //movie, game
    echo $param->value; //"http://www.youtube.com/v/..."
}
```

Comment: Read my update, the value of the Param will change constantly; so any way I can just pull the value from it like $favorites=movie.value? or something close to that?

Comment: You have the value written out and the value will always be different so not a static value ; will change upon different results query

Comment: How about that? That will just extract the value part.